# Efficient lag variable creation in large document term matrix in R

Tags: r, nlp

I am working with a rather large document term matrix (~280,000 terms) in R, and am wondering if there is an efficient way to create lag variables for each of my original terms.

The following example gives a document term matrix with three terms. This works for a toy example like this, but would be impossible for my data.

A quick note on the lag structure: I am exploring whether the appearance of any given term may have some cumulative, though diminishing, amount of importance over time.

```
dtm <- data.frame(revenue=c(1,2,3,3,5,6), up=c(1,1,0,3,1,1), sale=c(0,1,1,0,1,1))

for (i in 1:nrow(dtm)){
  if (i >=4){
    dtm$revenueLag4days[i] <- dtm$revenue[(i-3):i]%*%c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1)
    dtm$upLag4days[i] <- dtm$up[(i-3):i]%*% c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1)
    dtm$saleLag4days[i] <- dtm$sale[(i-3):i]%*% c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1)
  } else
    dtm$revenueLag4days[i]  <- dtm$upLag4days[i] <- dtm$saleLag4days[i] <- NA
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite this in a functional way for a document term matrix (~280,000 terms)?

Comment: check out the `?diff` function.  It is a touch limited but a first go to, when I need a lag variable.  
The description says it only works with times, but it actually works with integers as well.  It is considerably faster than a for loop (it took one of my operations from 8hrs to 60 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the `if` statement and creation of vectors within the loop slows you down a fair bit.  The loop below will be faster, and you could speed it up further by using parallel processing (e.g. `foreach`)

```
# Create a data.frame to store your results in
ans <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(dtm), ncol = ncol(dtm)))

# Give it the same column names as dtm
colnames(ans) <- colnames(dtm)

# Transpose dtm for matrix math
tdtm <- t(dtm)

# Create your row vector
mult_mat <- matrix(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), ncol = 1, nrow = 4)

# Loop through your matrix
for(i in 4:nrow(dtm)){
  ans[i,] <- tdtm[,(i-3):i] %*% mult_mat
}
```

This loop took ~52 seconds for a matrix with 280,000 columns and 100 rows.

Comment: Thanks, @M_Fidino. I am letting the server chew on this a bit. I am not sure if it will be able to handle allocating the large data.frame in your first line. I should have noted this in the beginning; my data is 280,000 columns by 15.4 million rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot allocate that much memory for my data. when creating 'ans' in your first line, I get the following error: 'Error: cannot allocate vector of size 16082.5 Gb'.

Comment: Yep. That would be a problem.

Comment: Haha! Thank you for the input, though. I have been using both the quanteda and tm packages to handle these large document term matrices. I am not sure what kind of memory wizardry they have used. It has me stumped.

Comment: Considering you only need to have a few rows of data open at a time you could subset the data by rows and work through it in chunks.

Comment: I can subset the data to work through it, but I ultimately need to re-join the data back to a larger whole. My ultimate goal is to use this use singular value decomposition on the lagged data. Do you think that it is possible to use a sparse triplet matrix from the slam package here? I have the original data in that form.

Comment: I've never used that package so I can't really say.  If you figure it out post an answer on here!

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I ended up subsetting my data down to a more reasonable size. I would still like to be able to use all of my data, and so I am going to try to figure out a way to implement the above loop over a sparse matrix in Rcpp.